# How to merge two Text/javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
  $('form[name=checkout_confirmation]').submit(function(){
  var return_value = false;

  if (!$('#matc').is(':checked')){
    alert(unescape('<?php echo MATC_TERMS_ALERT;?>'));
  }else{
    return_value = true;
  }

  return return_value;
  });
});
</script>
```

AND

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
     $("#confirmation .btn").click(function(){
        $(this).button('loading').delay(100000).queue(function() {
        });
     });
  });
</script>
```

I need the second function to load when `return_value = true;`.

Can anyone please help as to how i can merge these two function and run based on the else statement.

Comment: You can do `$("#confirmation .btn").trigger('click');` after `return_value = true;` in the first function?

Comment: Wrap second handler inside a function and call this function on `return true`

Comment: Hi Rajesh. I am not a programmer. Designing my website and learning as i go. Could you show me full solution please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just call the disered block when `return_value=true;`

```
$(function () {
    $('form[name=checkout_confirmation]').submit(function () {
        var return_value = false;

        if (!$('#matc').is(':checked')) {
            alert(unescape('<?php echo MATC_TERMS_ALERT;?>'));
        } else {

            // call of the desired block here
            $("#confirmation .btn").click(function () {
                $(this).button('loading').delay(100000).queue(function () {
                });
            });

            return_value = true;
        }

        return return_value;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Alexander. I tried that too. What that does is change the button on second click. Not on first click.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the second action into the first function where you want the action to take place..

```
$(function() {
    $('form[name=checkout_confirmation]').submit(function() {
        var return_value = false;
        if (!$('#matc').is(':checked')) {
            alert(unescape('<?php echo MATC_TERMS_ALERT;?>'));
        } else {
            return_value = true;
            $(this).button('loading').delay(100000).queue(function() {});
        }
        return return_value;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Rick. I thought that too. If i do that then it goes to next page showing loading... Rather than the bootstrap button turning to loading...